# Lookup Value With No Blank Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I need help with finding the proper code for looking up a value. From the screenshot, I would like to lookup "Brown" from Panel 1 but I continue to get blank spaces in between like Panel 2. My desired result would be Panel 3.

This is my first post so please feel free to tell me if I need to include anything!

[image: Sample Excel]

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, you can use the `FILTER` function. Assuming what you are looking for in table A2 to C6 is in cell F2, try the formula:

```
=FILTER($A$2:$C$6,$C$2:$C$6=$F$2,"")
```

[image]